# How to change the background color of thumb of slider in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty to change background color of thumb of slider using JavaScript. I have also tried answers that is already given in stackoverflow" Changing CSS pseudo-element styles via JavaScript"  but its not working for me.Basically, I just want to change the color of thumb using JavaScript. Can anyone help me please.

html

```
<input type="range" class="slider-range" id="range" value="7" name="range" min="1" step="1" max="7" >
```

CSS

```
.slider-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    background-color:#B49556;

}
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("range").classList.add('slider-range::-webkit-slider-thumb{background-color:yellow}');
```

Comment: If the closure as a duplicate was not sufficient, please comment on your original question explaining what you tried and why it didn't work for you, so that it can be explored further. Don't just re-post.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The same code that is above that I have treid so far and I am not able to change the color of thumb.I hope u can help me..

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol think you have closed my question without reading my problem's description. I hope u can help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Waiting for u to re-open my question. Thats not fair. You have closed my question without understanding my problem..